# HTML String to Element mootools

Tags: javascript, html, string, mootools

I'm looking for a way to create elements form string eg this doesnt work:

```
$('some').adopt('<span>test</span>');
```

you must use `new Element` but i have a huge html string. I could do this:

```
new Element('div', {html: hugeHtmlString});
```

but its so wrong. why can't it be as simple as it is in jquery

Comment: Where is the big difference between `new Element(...)` and `$(...)`?

Comment: http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Elements.From

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Elements.From

does the job

Answer (score 0):

The following thread proposes a number of solutions:

http://mootools-users.660466.n2.nabble.com/Moo-New-element-from-html-string-td3557543.html